# Graph field in three-dimensional space inside a circle using tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

Let me show what I want:

[image: Original]

*This field not correspond with that I want but the idea is the same.*

Although this is what I got... (using `tikzpicture` environment):

[image: I do this]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{vmargin}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=red,fill=white,very thick,only marks,mark=*}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{vmargin}

\setpapersize{A4}
\setmargins{2.2cm}
{0.5cm}
{16.5cm}
{23.42cm}
{30pt}
{1cm}
{0pt}
{2cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\large \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \begin{axis}[
            legend pos=outer north east,
            axis lines = center,
            label style={font=\tiny},
            legend style={font=\tiny},
            xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            zticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            xlabel = $x$,
            xmin=-4,
            ymin=-4,
            zmin=-4,
            xmax=4,
            ymax=4,
            zmax=4,
            ylabel = $y$,
            zlabel = $z$,
            domain=-3:3,
            domain y=-3:3,
            restrict z to domain=-3:3,
            view={160}{20}
        ]
            % Field
            \addplot3[opacity=0.9,surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,samples=60] {y*x*x-y};
            \addlegendentry{$f(x,y)$}
            % This planes should be circles...
            \addplot3[samples=20] {2};
            \addplot3[samples=20] {-2};
            % Points:
            \addplot3[soldot,black] coordinates {(sqrt(3),1,2)} node[above left] {\tiny $(\sqrt 3,1,2)$};
            \addplot3[soldot,black] coordinates {(-sqrt(3),1,2)} node[above right] {\tiny $(-\sqrt 3,1,2)$};
            \addplot3[soldot,black] coordinates {(sqrt(3),-1,-2)} node[below left] {\tiny $(\sqrt 3,-1,-2)$};
            \addplot3[soldot,black] coordinates {(-sqrt(3),-1,-2)} node[below right] {\tiny $(-\sqrt 3,-1,-2)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Very bad, no? `:'D`

If possible, I need to make the original image look as good as possible with your help. The samples of the field are `60` and no more because after that value I get the error: `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]`. Sorry, my bad computer `:)`.

I would like to keep the limits of the axes but in the figure do **not appear those pointed spikes** that are horrible... I mean these spikes:

[image: Spikes of the field]

Also correct the view would be awesome (and trying to **not adding an `opacity` command**).

Is there any way to achieve that in the simplest way?

Thank you!!

*P.S: the field is `f(x, y) = y * x^2 - y` in the circle `x^2 + y^2 <= 4`.*

*P.S.2: I hope that those people who are anxious in Rio also collaborate `:P`.*

Comment: Off-topic: don't use `vmargin`.

Comment: OK, that `package` remained of the complete document.

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't use it in your real document either! You shouldn't use it at all. Use `geometry` instead. `geometry` has some bugs, but they are mere midges in comparison with the mosquitos and giant hornets of `vmargin`.

Comment: You might be able to avoid the capacity errors with LuaTeX.

Comment: I use the `LaTeX->PS->PDF` output but if I change it to `LuaTeX->PDF` output I get the following error: `TeXnicCenter: [DocOpen(%bm.pdf)][FileOpen("%bmp.p...   Cannot execute the command`.

Comment: The spikes come from the parametrization and the fact that pgfplots uses little rectangles (in the parametrization). It becomes slightly better if you drop `restrict z to domain=-3:3,` and use `\addplot3[opacity=0.9,surf,mesh/ordering=y
   varies,shader=interp,samples=60,domain=0:3,domain y=0:360] 
   ({x*cos(y)},{x*sin(y)},{min(max(x*x*x*cos(y)*cos(y)*sin(y)-x*sin(y),-3),3)});`. Need to go hiking to meet some fellow marmots now. ;-)

Comment: ... and I would use polar coordinates for the upper and lower circle as well, if you want them to be circles.

Comment: @marmot go in peace!! Answer when you come back `:))`. That complex-unreadable-beatiful code works much better than mine... I could decipher something but I do not understand why you make the minimum between the maximum between sines and cosines, `-3` and `3`. You are a *beast*, or rather, a smart marmot.

Comment: However there are some pending issues, such as rotating the graph in such a way that we can see all the maximun and minimun and opacity well-defined. Anyway, I have another couple of graphics that I would like to do. Can I do it myself or resort to TeX.SE? Hehe.

Comment: @marmot about using polar coordinates on that circle, I used only for doing integrals. I don't know how to graph them. Anyway I did the following: the circle is `x^2 + y^2 = 4`, so using polar coordinates I have the set `{(ρ, θ) ∈ |R^2 | 0 ≤ ρ ≤ 2 and 0 ≤ θ ≤ 2π}`. Btw I don't know how to graph the upper and lower circle. Could you help, please?

Comment: @marmot Actually with polar coordinates you could 'simply' use `\addplot3[opacity=0.9,surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,samples=60,variable=t,variable y=r,domain=0:360,domain y=0:2] ({r*cos(t)},{r*sin(t)},{r*r*r*sin(t)*cos(t)*cos(t)-r*sin(t)});`, without the `min` and `max` functions. I used `r` and `t` for ρ and θ just for readability.

Comment: @MaxSnippe good job! What can we do about points, view, circles, etc?

Comment: @manooooh Wel the circles could be plotted with `\addplot3[samples=30,smooth,variable=t,domain=0:360] ({2*cos(t)},{2*sin(t)},2);`. The view can be adjusted with the `view={}{}` option that you already have in your MWE (`view={110}{25}`) seems a good value. Maybe you can add `axis on top` so you can delete the opacity option, but this will not give a good 3D effect. And what is wrong with the points?

Comment: @MaxSnippe works pretty good with all your recomendations! I think I will leave the opacity to show the background. With respect to the points I was a bit afraid to create the same graphic but seen in the `xy`-plane, but I only had to modify their positions to leave the graphic in all its splendor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed the definition of your function slightly, such that it only exists in the circle `x^2 + y^2 <= 4`. I also changed the shading, because I think the shape is a little more clear this way. The capacity problem can be solved by changing the number of samples taken for `x` and `y` (`t` and `r` in this plot) separately. Big thanks to @marmot for the idea to use polar coordinates.

```
\addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=faceted,samples=72,samples y=20,variable=t,variable y=r,domain=0:360,domain y=0:2,line join=round] ({r*cos(t)},{r*sin(t)},{r*r*r*sin(t)*cos(t)*cos(t)-r*sin(t)});
```

I used `r` and `t` for ρ and θ just for readability. The circles can also be drawn with polar coordinates, using

```
\addplot3[samples=30,smooth,variable=t,domain=0:360] ({2*cos(t)},{2*sin(t)},2);
```

I also added the `axis on top` option to make the `opacity=0.9` redundant, but this does not give a proper 3D effect. This should be something for a different question I think. The view is changed using the `view={}{}` key, I found `view={110}{25}` to be pretty good.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=red,fill=white,very thick,only marks,mark=*}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \begin{axis}[
            legend pos=outer north east,
            axis lines = center,
            label style={font=\tiny},
            legend style={font=\tiny},
            xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            zticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            xlabel = $x$,
            xmin=-4,
            ymin=-4,
            zmin=-4,
            xmax=4,
            ymax=4,
            zmax=4,
            ylabel = $y$,
            zlabel = $z$,
            domain=-3:3,
            domain y=-3:3,
            view={110}{25},
            axis on top,
        ]
            % Field
%            \addplot3[opacity=0.9,surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,samples=60] {y*x*x-y};
            \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=faceted,samples=72,samples y=20,variable=t,variable y=r,domain=0:360,domain y=0:2,line join=round] ({r*cos(t)},{r*sin(t)},{r*r*r*sin(t)*cos(t)*cos(t)-r*sin(t)});
            \addlegendentry{$f(x,y)$}
            % This planes should be circles...
            \addplot3[samples=30,smooth,variable=t,domain=0:360] ({2*cos(t)},{2*sin(t)},2);
            \addplot3[samples=30,smooth,variable=t,domain=0:360] ({2*cos(t)},{2*sin(t)},-2);
            % Points:
            \addplot3[soldot,black] coordinates {(sqrt(3),1,2)} node[above left] {\tiny $(\sqrt 3,1,2)$};
            \addplot3[soldot,black] coordinates {(-sqrt(3),1,2)} node[above right] {\tiny $(-\sqrt 3,1,2)$};
            \addplot3[soldot,black] coordinates {(sqrt(3),-1,-2)} node[below left] {\tiny $(\sqrt 3,-1,-2)$};
            \addplot3[soldot,black] coordinates {(-sqrt(3),-1,-2)} node[below right] {\tiny $(-\sqrt 3,-1,-2)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And of course the result:

[image]

*Disclaimer: I did not solve the position of the points and their label placements, I will leave that to you `:)`*

**Edit**
As per request, when looking from the positive z-axis and with smaller axes limits, the point labels were clipped. Using `clip=false` prevents this.

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=red,fill=white,very thick,only marks,mark=*}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \begin{axis}[
            legend pos=outer north east,
            axis lines = center,
            label style={font=\tiny},
            legend style={font=\tiny},
            xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            zticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            xlabel = $x$,
%            xmin=-4,
%            ymin=-4,
            xmin=-2.5,
            ymin=-2.5,
            zmin=-4,
%            xmax=4,
%            ymax=4,
            xmax=2.5,
            ymax=2.5,
            zmax=4,
            ylabel = $y$,
            zlabel = $z$,
            domain=-3:3,
            domain y=-3:3,
%            view={110}{25},
            view={0}{90},
            axis on top,
            clip=false,
        ]
            % Field
%            \addplot3[opacity=0.9,surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,samples=60] {y*x*x-y};
            \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=faceted,samples=72,samples y=20,variable=t,variable y=r,domain=0:360,domain y=0:2,line join=round] ({r*cos(t)},{r*sin(t)},{r*r*r*sin(t)*cos(t)*cos(t)-r*sin(t)});
            \addlegendentry{$f(x,y)$}
            % This planes should be circles...
            \addplot3[samples=30,smooth,variable=t,domain=0:360] ({2*cos(t)},{2*sin(t)},2);
            \addplot3[samples=30,smooth,variable=t,domain=0:360] ({2*cos(t)},{2*sin(t)},-2);
            % Points:
            \addplot3[soldot,black] coordinates {(sqrt(3),1,2)} node[above right] {\tiny $(\sqrt 3,1,2)$};
            \addplot3[soldot,black] coordinates {(-sqrt(3),1,2)} node[above left] {\tiny $(-\sqrt 3,1,2)$};
            \addplot3[soldot,black] coordinates {(sqrt(3),-1,-2)} node[below right] {\tiny $(\sqrt 3,-1,-2)$};
            \addplot3[soldot,black] coordinates {(-sqrt(3),-1,-2)} node[below left] {\tiny $(-\sqrt 3,-1,-2)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Excellent work! I did the label placements of the points... but is good for you to know that I am having a little problem `:)`. I crushed the function in the `xy`-plane (using the same code but with `view{0}{90}`)and drew the points with their respective coordinates, but unfortunately the position of the text of each point is cut off because the x axis goes from `-2.5` to `2.5` and the text needs more horizontal space. For example, use this view that I mention and modify the first point by this code:

Comment: You can add `clip=false` to the axis options to prevent the clipping of stuff drawn outside the graph area.

Comment: `\addplot3[soldot,black] coordinates {(sqrt(3),1,2)} node[above right] {\tiny $(\sqrt 3,1,2)$};`. The left parenthesis is not visible (and this for the rest of the points). I tried adding in the `axis` environment this: `xshift=-10cm` but it doesn't work (besides, the text on the right would not be seen with this line of code either). How could you fix that? Do you need me to edit my message with my requirement?

Comment: Never mind! You fixed that

Comment: Updated the answer :)

Comment: Off-topic: I forgot the saddle points haha! (This time I solved it by myself)

Comment: I agree with your comment above. (I had 60 seconds for testing and writing my comment. ;-) +1 of course.

Comment: @MaxSnippe now I have this surface: `\addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,samples=70,samples y=50,variable=t,variable y=r,domain=0:360,domain y=-1:1,restrict z to domain=-3:1] ({r*cos(t)},{r*sin(t)},{3*r*r-3});` a paraboloid of equation `z = 3x^2 + 3y^2 - 3`. However, when I compile it generates [these imperfections](https://imgur.com/a/IHCQxb0). I tried increasing the samples of the `y` coordinate but after `50` it generates me error. How can it be solved?

Comment: @manooooh The comments are not really for follow-up questions. Besides that, if you ask this as a new question, it will get more attention and therefore probably a better answer, so please ask a new question and I would be happy to reply there.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, an option adapted in asymptote

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
% arara: asymptote
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
    \begin{asy}
        import three;
        import graph3;
        import grid3;   
        size(400,600);
        currentprojection=orthographic(5,1.5,1);
        //scale(Linear, Linear, Linear);
        limits((-5,-3,-3),(5,3,3));

        triple f(pair t) {
        return (2*t.y*cos(t.x),2*t.y*sin(t.x),2*t.y*sin(t.x)-8*t.y*sin(t.x)*cos(t.x)*cos(t.x));
        }
        triple g(pair t) {
        return (2*t.y*cos(t.x),2*t.y*sin(t.x),-2);
        }
        triple h(pair t) {
        return (2*t.y*cos(t.x),2*t.y*sin(t.x),2);
        }
        triple j(pair t) {
        return (3*t.x,3*t.y,0);
        }

        pen p=rgb(0,0,0)+thick();
        surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(2pi,1),120,5,Spline);
        surface t=surface(g,(0,0),(2pi,1),90,5,Spline);
        surface u=surface(h,(0,0),(2pi,1),90,5,Spline);
        surface v=surface(j,(-1,-1),(1,1),1,1,Spline);

        //surface only
        //draw(s,lightgray);

        // mesh only
         draw(v,surfacepen=material(white+opacity(0.8),
         ambientpen=gray),meshpen=p);
         draw(s,surfacepen=material(purple+opacity(0.5),
         ambientpen=purple),meshpen=p);
         draw(t,surfacepen=material(white+opacity(0.5),
         ambientpen=white),meshpen=p);
         draw(u,surfacepen=material(white+opacity(0.5),
         ambientpen=white),meshpen=p);
         path3 i=(sqrt(3),-1,2)..(sqrt(3),1,-2)..(0,2,2)..(-sqrt(3),1,-2)..(-sqrt(3),-1,2)..(0,-2,-2)..cycle;
         dot(i,8bp+.8blue);
         label("D",(sqrt(3),-1,2),N);
         label("A",(sqrt(3),1,-2),N);
         label("C",(0,2,2),N);
         label("E",(-sqrt(3),1,-2),N);
         label("B",(-sqrt(3),-1,2),N);
         label("F",(0,-2,-2),N);
         xaxis3(Label("$x$",1),red,arrow=Arrow3,OutTicks(Step=1));
         yaxis3(Label("$y$",1),green,arrow=Arrow3,OutTicks(Step=1));
         zaxis3(Label("$z$",1),blue,arrow=Arrow3,OutTicks(Step=1));

        // surface & mesh
        //draw(s,lightgray,meshpen=p,render(merge=true));

    \end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the colors!! `:)`.